# Помогите сохранить вкладки и их текст в формате html с помощью pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qsettings

В QTabWidget необходимо при закрытии сохранить состояние вкладок, их текст внутри в формате html.
Примеры подобных решений: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745570/how-to-save-current-values-of-qtablewidget

Comment: Vlad VarnoVo, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует вашу пробу решения задачи.